# Анимация в jquery

Tags: jquery, анимация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы анимация была не как сейчас у меня снизу вверх сворачивала див, а наоборот раскрывала его сверху-вниз.

Вот что я имею:

```
$('.content').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    height: 'toggle'
}, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально скройте блок или в css - *display: none;*, или в JS - *$('.content').hide();*

Вот, [как это будет выглядеть](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/9nRPc/1/).